# How to disable default value in multiple ui-select angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs, laravel, ui-select

I am having a multiple ui-select control on my page where user is selecting usergroup from the dropdown and I want the very first selected option in my control to be disabled so that user cannot delete its own group.

My code looks like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in UserGroups">
    <ui-select multiple
                       class="col-md-8 input-sm"
                       ng-model="item.selectedUserGroup"
                       theme="bootstrap">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select field...">{{$item.group_name}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices
                        repeat="grp in AccessGroups | filter:$select.search">
                    <div ng-bind-html="grp.group_name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select></tr>
```

where AccessGroups is an object

```
$scope.AccessGroups = [
       {group_id: "1", group_name: "Portfolio Manager"},
    {group_id: "2", group_name: "Risk Manager"},
    {group_id: "3", group_name: "Analyst"},
    {group_id: "4", group_name: "Operations"}]
```

And the whole ui-select is placed under ng-repeat

Where one one looks like this:

```
$scope.UserGroups = [
               {benchmark_id:"38",
                benchmark_name:"Test ",
                group_name:"5,1",
                selectedUserGroup:Array(2)[{group_id: "5",
                                            group_name: "Administrator"},
                                            {group_id: "1",
                                            group_name: "Portfolio Manager"}]
                 }]
```

Can you guys help me?

I am stuck at this point.

I have tried removing the X sign from UI it worked but I am not able to do it pro-grammatically.
Please look at the image to get the idea.
[image: picture having view of control on the page]

Comment: Why would you not instead remove that option completely? It seems like a UI distraction to have it in there.

Comment: no actually i need the default group to be shown as selected but the user need to delete its own group

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if it can be taken as solutio to my problem technically but it worked for me.
I simply remove the cross sign from very first entry of the selected value with the help of css selectors which prevents user from removing there own usergroups.

I used this CSS Selecter to remove cross sign

```
#benchmarkCreated > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr> td:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > span > span:nth-child(1) > span > span.close.ui-select-match-close{
   display: none;
}
```